# How to retrieve only specific field of a document with Spring Data Mongo DB?

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

For example, I have a collection with the documents like:

```
class Group {
  @Id
  @Field( '_id' )
  UUID id

  @Field( 'title' )
  String title
}
```

I have a repository:
`interface GroupRepository extends MongoRepository<Group, UUID> { }`
How can I retrieve a list of all identifiers?
I don't wanna retrieve all documents, and then collect the ids. I would like to have a method like: `List<UUID> findAllGroupIds()`.
Is it possible without explicit implementation with `Criteria`? I've tried to use `@Query`, but it didn't give the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MongoDB aggregation framework to retrieve a list of ids.

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(stages.add(project("_id")));

AggregationResults<UUID> ids = mongoOperation.aggregate(agg,
                "Group", UUID.class);
```